# Facing odd behaviour with Long.parseLong()

Tags: java, android, type-conversion

I'm facing a pretty strange behaviour with `Long.parseLong()` method while trying to extract a number out of a string.

The string contains multiple numbers but only one (which I need) is within question marks, so I extract it using regex and then I try to parse the 15 digits number into a long variable:

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\"\\d+\"");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(myString);
    while (m.find()) {
        String var1 = m.group();
        var1 = var1.replace("\"", "");

        try {
            long var2 = Long.parseLong(var1);
            return var2;
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            return -1L;
        }
    }
    return 0L;
```

Although I expect it to return `var2` or throw an exception, the next line that's being called after `Long.parseLong(var1)` is `return 0L` and I have no idea why. Am I missing something?

Thanks.

Comment: [Works for me](http://ideone.com/l2kjLy). Why not put the digits in a group, so you don't have to replace the quotes?

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the method with a debugger to see if the operations are giving you the results you expect?

Comment: Could you provide sample string ?

Comment: @AndyTurner When I'm printing instead of returning, everything works as expected. The problem occurs only when returning.

Comment: @scottb Yes, var1 contains the expected string (for example '123451234512345'), the problem is occurs only when reaching `Long.parseLong()`.

Comment: @g-t Here's a random sample (adjusted as a string in the code editor): "abc 350 \"123451234512345\" a2"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code works as expected when taking the returning part out of the `while(m.find())` loop:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\"\\d+\"");
Matcher m = p.matcher(myString);
String var = "-1";
    while (m.find()) {
        var = m.group().replace("\"", "");
    }
return Long.parseLong(var);
```

I fail to understand it as it does work when printing and not returning, and it also does work within the loop in g-t's example. If you're willing to elaborate on this case, I'd like to read.

Answer (score 0):

I've just run your code like that:

```
public static void main(String [] args) {
    String myString = "abc 350 \"123451234512345\"";
    System.out.println(doSth(myString));
}

public static long doSth(final String myString) {
    final Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\"\\d+\"");
    final Matcher m = p.matcher(myString);

    while (m.find()) {
        String var1 = m.group().replace("\"", "");

        try {
            return Long.parseLong(var1);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return -1L;
        }
    }

    return 0L;
}
```

And I get:

```
123451234512345

Process finished with exit code 0
```

It may be a problem connected to .classess files. Try to rebuild your project (mvn clean / gradle clean / find . -type f -name "*.class" -exec rm -rf {} \;).

I suppose your .class file doesn't match the code in .java file.

Comment: I tried to rebuild and even invalidate cache, and yet the behvaiour reoccurs. It's worth to mention that I run it in an AsyncTask, but I can't see why it may be related.

Comment: Have you tried debugging ? Try to evaluate Long.parseLong()

Comment: What does it mean ? Which debugger you use ? In intellij idea you can evaluate a part of code during debugging. It'd be very useful in this case.

Comment: I'm coding in IntelliJ IDEA. I'm using Evaluate/Watches for this case and in there it works just fine. I also debugged the `Long.parseLong()` method itself and it also gives back the expected number. It just doesn't return to the calling method.